# Autogenerate ReportClass for Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm fairly new to Crystal Reports. I have recently taken over an ASP .NET project which contains some crystal reports. There are some .rpt files with corresponding .vb files. The VB files define classes which inherit from ReportClass. I have made a new Crystal report and added it to the solution, but I only have the .rpt file and I have no idea how to generate the corresponding ReportClass. Does anyone know how to do this?

**Edit**
I've edited the file's Custom Tool property to be "CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportCodeGenerator" and change the Build Action to "Embedded Resource" and then right-clicked the file and selected **"Run Custom Tool."** I get an error:

> "Cannot find custom tool
>   'CrystalDecisions.VSDesigner.CodeGen.ReportCodeGenerator' on this
>   system."

FYI I have Crystal Reports XI installed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't generate when you build the project? Did you try specifying the same "custom tool" to use in the vs properties on the .rpt file?

Comment: OK, did that. Doesn't seem to generate it though.

Comment: hmm, but the existing reports generate with that tool? I wonder if this has something to do with XI and VS Crystal 10.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I spent some time trying to figure out this same problem. Here is my solution as long as your Crystal Report is working correctly to begin with.

- Add the .rpt and the .vb file to your solution
- click on the .rpt file and select Properties
- set Build Action to "Embedded Resource
- set Copy to Output Directory to "Copy always"
- Rebuild solution and test.